# Platform-independent C++ Debugger IDEs that follow pointers like Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, pointers, debugging

Visual Studio debugger automatically recognizes the types of pointers and shows the value of the variable or object pointed to by the pointer.  Example screenshot for Ruby debugger here:  http://www.rubyinside.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/jruby-debugger.jpg   This applies to debugger tooltips, watch windows, etc.  I never have to see the value of a pointer.  Same thing happens for arrays.

Are there platform-independent (preferably free/open source) debugger IDEs that allow this for C++?  I tried Code::Blocks, Geany, Eclipse, etc., they all just show the value of the pointer (looking like 0xE0CCDB34).  There could possibly be settings in these IDEs but I could not find it.

My main interest is to be able to compile and debug C++ with GCC/MinGW toolchains.  So if no platform-independent IDE debuggers support this, are there any free ones on Windows that use GCC/MinGW toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger included in [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) does this.

Answer (score 0):

[DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) will do what you're asking, and I believe it can be compiled for Windows using GCC. It's not an IDE, but a very capable debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I use emacs + gud

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrandUnifiedDebugger

http://www.inet.net.nz/~nickrob/

beware, emacs has a steep learning curve which never ends.

Comment: Or use vim. It is like emacs but better :)

Comment: @Adam `(gheto-queen-voice "oh no you dint")` :-)

Comment: Programming with vim/emacs feels like trying to hammer a nail with a swiss army knife

Answer (score 0):

The c++ interpreter/compiler/REPL in [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) is called [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint), and has the ability to insert breakpoints (`-b` on the command-line or `.b` in the interpreter), at which time you can print the values of variables; access members; invoke functions and methods; manipulate memory; and so on very much like a traditional debugger.

And ROOT runs on many platforms.

Cint is separable from ROOT and can be used in other contexts, but I have no experience with doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that [CodeLite IDE](http://www.codelite.org/) also supports this.